# gimp source build error g_module_build_path

Tags: 12.04, gimp, source-code, source, gtk-2

I m trying to build gimp 2.8 from source, all dependencies are me but now while if "make" on it it gives this error:

```
/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so: error: undefined reference to
'g_module_build_path'
```

My os is ubuntu 12.04 x86

Comment: Looks like a GIMP bug. Maybe you should make sure you have the latest version of GIMP and check the bugtracker. If that doesn't turn up anything, update your compilers.

Comment: Neither that library nor the procedure is part of GIMP. Are all development package dependencies present on the system?

Comment: ./configure shows no error and i have even manually checked to dependencies as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is make sure that it gets linked with the right libraries. The real bug is in the pgkconfig file for gtk2. So all you have to do is open it as root and add -lgobject-2.0 to the list of libraries. Then rerun configure, make clean and then make all and it will work perfectly.